# Not able to access elements with kotlin in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to android studio and wanted to make a pretty basic app. The problem is after creating an  xml file and giving it id as `btnApply`, i tried to print something when it gets clicked. I think the code is correct as I have been following a youtube tutorial, but something else like my settings is not allowing me to access the xml file elements. Any fixes??

```
package com.example.applicationone

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnApply.setOnClickListner{
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Button Clicked")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `btnApply`, you first have to declare it. Instead use `findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnApply)` Also, if you want to learn android, [google's course](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course) might be a good start.
Use the code below if `btnApply` is your button's id

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnApply).setOnClickListner{
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Button Clicked")
}
```

Comment: i was always using this style, until i found out how to make the code in question right. add this to app gradle file ::::   

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

Answer (score 1):

If you've been following some tutorial, it's probably using the deprecated *Kotlin synthetics* library that automagically looks up views when you refer to them without declaring them. Either move to [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) (which is basically the same thing except you access your IDs on a `Binding` object you initialise) or look them up the basic way with `findViewById` like in Vaishnav's answer